# How can I receive an event from Electron in a Non-Electron Web Page

Tags: node.js, electron

I get how to communicate between an electron process and a web page within electron and I have seen examples of that on the web using IPCrenderer

If I have a web page that is completely outside of electron ( in this case a vue.js web application )  - but then I wrap it inside an electron app - how can I receive events from within the web application?

To understand the bigger picture, I have a web application that I want to use mainly on the web, but for one of the pages, I need to be able to send and receive between the web page and barcode scanners / serial scales. I can manage USB events within Electron, I am just unsure what to put in the web page to receive events sent from Electron when it is wrapping the web page.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using websockets, with e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws ? It's the same principle as IPC, but allows two-way communication outside Electron.